# Trying to create an ISO of my bootable USB using the unix command: dd

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, iso-image, dd

i'm trying to create a (bootable) ISO (which i'll then burn to dvd) from the source being an bootable USB disk (it contains windows 7 and i've installed a number of PC's from it already).

So i'm trying to use `dd` to make the iso.

So first up I'm trying to find the mount info :-

```
df -h

Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   120Gi   82Gi   37Gi    69%    /
devfs          191Ki  191Ki    0Bi   100%    /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%    /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%    /home
/dev/disk0s4   112Gi  4.0Mi  112Gi     1%    /Volumes/BOOTCAMP
/dev/disk2s1   7.5Gi  3.1Gi  4.4Gi    42%    /Volumes/WINDOWS 7
```

Next, I try the following (from the Desktop folder...) :-

```
dd if=/dev/disk2s1 of=win7.iso
```

and I get the error message

```
dd: /dev/disk2s1: Resource busy
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried unmounting it before running `dd`?

Comment: yes - when I eject it, the `df` command doesn't show the usb any more?

Comment: but if ejected you will not be able to read it! try `umount /dev/disk2s1` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my own answer.

I ended up typing

```
dd if=/dev/disk2 of=~/win7.iso
```

Note 1: The usb is `disk2`, not `disk2s1`. No idea why? Obviously, I do not understand the output of the `df` command.

Note 2: I had to make sure I used a correct writable path, for the output file.